# how to get access tokens from refresh token? does refresh token expire?

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a python script which takes a (.csv with access tokens and a file) as input and uploads that file to multiple google drives whose access tokens are in that csv
but after sometime access tokens get expired and I have to get them again...just saw there's something called refresh and it refreshes access token

> Is it possible to do this from python script, please explain.

> Do refresh token expire?

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers = {}
para = {
    "name": "update",
}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open("./update.txt", "rb")
}
tokens = pd.read_csv('tokens.csv')
for i in tokens.token:
    headers={"Authorization": i}
    r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
        headers=headers,
        files=files
    )
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: you need to provide some code or a working example for others to accurately answer

Comment: I've added the code please check

Comment: to answer your question, access tokens do expire, you need to periodically fetch new ones

Comment: can i do that from python script, without going to google api console?

Comment: yes you will probably have to make an API request to get a new token, you'll need to find the documentation specific to what you are using

Comment: is it possible to provide that code..it might be one or two lines...please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233522/discussion-between-mohan-krishna-karthik-and-gold-cy).

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to get [a new `access_token` programmatically using a `refresh_token`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline), you must have set `access_type` to `offline` when [redirecting the user to Google's OAuth 2.0 server](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#redirecting).

If you did that, you can get a new `access_token` if you do the following `POST` request to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
refresh_token=refresh_token&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

The corresponding response would be something like:

```
{
  "access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in": 3920,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

#### Note:

You can find code snippets for several languages in the reference I provide below, including Python, but considering you are not using the Python library, I think the HTTP/REST snippet I provided might be more useful in your situation.

#### Reference:

- [Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)

Answer (score 0):

You can use request lib to generate access token from refresh token:

```
import requests

# Replace these with your OAuth2 credentials and refresh token
client_id = '****.apps.googleusercontent.com'
client_secret = '****'
refresh_token = '***'

# URL for token exchange
token_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'

# Set the data to be sent in the POST request to refresh the token
data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'refresh_token': refresh_token,
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
}

# Send the POST request to refresh the token
response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Successful token refresh
    token_data = response.json()
    access_token = token_data['access_token']
    print(f"Refreshed access token: {access_token}")
else:
    # Handle error cases
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
```

You can replicate the scenario first in Google Oauth2.0 Playground and generate refresh token and then use it here.